# Error with Geocode, Rails and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, geocode

I'm using Rails 3.2.16, mongoid and geocode.

I've set up the model for my profile to convert the street and city address into long/lat. This is working well. I also have a search that's based on geocode - which also works. It searches for profiles with in certain distances etc.

Even when I misspell a city in the search it's intelligent enough to figure out what I actually mean.

However, when I search for something that really stumps geocode, like "sgervwsewerw", it throws the "We're sorry, but something went wrong" error. How can I prevent this error and just have it send back no results? Here is the error information:

```
Processing by ProfilesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "profile_search"=>"sgervwsewerw"}
  Rendered profiles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (137.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 489.6ms

ActionView::Template::Error (The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Query
  @length=208
  @request_id=2
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="tango_production.profiles"
  @skip=0
  @limit=0
  @selector={"$query"=>{"coordinates"=>{"$nearSphere"=>[NaN, NaN], "$maxDistance"=>0.0063151153689165445}}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 16433: "point not in interval of [ -180, 180 ] :: caused by :: { 0: nan.0, 1: nan.0 }"

See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md
for details about this error.):
```

Here is the code from my profile controller:

```
def index
 if params[:profile_search].present?
    @profiles = Profile.near(params[:profile_search], 25, :order => :distance).desc("position_order")
  else
    @profiles = Profile.desc("position_order")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in the NaN argument in the $nearSphere for coordinates.
Make sure, you provide correct values for the comparison (e.g. if using the users location, make sure it is available).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

In your mongoid.yml initializer file you will find a line like:

```
# Raise an error when performing a #find and the document is not found.
# (default: true)
raise_not_found_error: false
```

default it's true, if you set it to false you will not get this error anymore.

Comment: I'm still get the error after doing that unfortunately.

Comment: The conversion too lat/long seems to return `NaN`. You could check if the lat/long is blank or not before sending it to mongoid.

Comment: What you said makes sense. However, after trying a couple things (guessing really) I couldn't figure out how to it. Any tips on what I can do? I'm basically looking to see if a valid result is returned.

Comment: you can first take the `params[:profile_search]` and get the lat\long of it by using for example:
`Geocoder.coordinates("25 Main St, Cooperstown, NY")`

You get an array of latitude and longitude which you can use. If this returns a nil however you should not query the db.